# Show, that ${\rm M}(n,\mathbb{K})={\rm S}(n,\mathbb{K})\oplus {\rm T}(n,\mathbb{K})$

Tags: linear-algebra

> The set ${\rm M}(n,\mathbb{K})$ of the $n\times n$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{K}$ together with the matrix addition and the scalar matrix multiplication form a vector space. An $n\times n$-matrix $A$ with the entries $a_{ij}\; 1\leq i,j\leq n$, means symmetrical, if for all $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$ applies that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. A matrix is called skew-symmetric, if for all $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$ it applies that $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$. Let ${\rm S}(n,\mathbb{K})$ be the set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{K}$ and ${\rm T}(n,\mathbb{K})$ be the set of skew symmetric $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{K}$.

Show, that ${\rm M}(n,\mathbb{K})={\rm S}(n,\mathbb{K})\oplus {\rm T}(n,\mathbb{K})$

Does the $\oplus$  mean the addition over $\mathbb{K}$ or the direct sum?

EDIT:
Could I use the $\dim$ formula too? I already determined the dimension of skew symmetric matrices and symmetric matrices which are $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ and $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$. The dimension of the set of all matrices is $n\cdot n = n^2 $ Because $\frac{n^2-n}{2}+\frac{n^2+n}{2}=n^2$ we can assume, that ${\rm M}(n,\mathbb{K})={\rm S}(n,\mathbb{K})\oplus {\rm T}(n,\mathbb{K})$ Therefore, $\dim({\rm S}\cap {\rm T})=0\implies {\rm S}\cap {\rm T} =\{0\}$

Comment: You can use the dimension formula to prove the equivalence $M=S+T \iff S\cap T = \{0\}$. But still, you have to show either $M=S+T$ or $S\cap T=\{0\}$.

Comment: And if the characteristic of the field is 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation says that any $n \times n$ matrix can be written uniquely as $S+T$ where $S$ is a symmetric matrix and $T$ is a skew symmetric matrix. To show this define $s_{ij}=\frac {m_{ij}+m_{ji}} 2$ and $t_{ij}=\frac {m_{ij}-m_{ji}} 2$. You can verify that this gives the desired form. If We have two such representations $M=S+T=M_1+T_1$ then $S-S_1=T_1-T$. Use the fact that if  a matrix is symmetric as well as skew symmetric then it is the zero matrix to show that $S=S_1$ and $T=T_1$. [$T_1-T$ is symmetric and $S-S_1$ is skew symmetric].

Comment: Could I use the $\dim$ formula too? I already determined the dimension of skew symmetric matrices and symmetric matrices which are $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ and $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$. The dimension of the set of all matrices is $n\cdot n = n^2 $ Because $\frac{n^2-n}{2}+\frac{n^2+n}{2}=n^2$ we can assume, that $M(n,K)=S(n,K)\oplus T(n,K)$ Therefore, $\dim(S\cap T)=0=\{0\}$

Comment: Yes, but that requires a proof. It is much simpler to just use the definition to prove that $S \cap T=\{0\}$.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to hold on to your hint / solution